# css-loader unknown word when building webpack prod profile for a JHipster angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, css-loader

I have build an application using `JHIPSTER` and everything is fine when running `npm-start` in dev environment but when I run the command `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`

I got this error:
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):

> CssSyntaxError
>
> (2:9) Unknown word
>
> 1 |
>
> > 2 |         var result = require("!!../../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./home-dashboard.component.css");
> >         |         ^   3 |    4 |         if (typeof result === "string") {

This is my `webpack.prod.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'production';
const sass = require('sass');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build.
    // You have to enable it in Terser config below and in tsconfig-aot.json as well
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('build/resources/main/static/'),
        filename: 'app/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: '../'
                    }
                },
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: '../'
                    }
                },
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        }]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
                // sourceMap: true, // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 6,
                    ie8: false,
                    toplevel: true,
                    module: true,
                    compress: {
                        dead_code: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        properties: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        conditionals: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        toplevel: true,
                        if_return: true,
                        inline: true,
                        join_vars: true,
                        ecma: 6,
                        module: true,
                        toplevel: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false,
                        indent_level: 2,
                        ecma: 6
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        module: true,
                        toplevel: true
                    }
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: 'content/[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: 'content/[id].css'
        }),
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: [
                    'en',
                    'nl',
                    'fr'
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-moment-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
        }),
        new Visualizer({
            // Webpack statistics in target folder
            filename: '../stats.html'
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            mainPath: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
            tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          skipWaiting: true,
        })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
});
```

And this is my `webpack.common.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const MergeJsonWebpackPlugin = require("merge-jsons-webpack-plugin");

const utils = require('./utils.js');

module.exports = (options) => ({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            app: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/'),
            ...rxPaths()
        }
    },
    stats: {
        children: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes:false,
                    minifyJS:false,
                    minifyCSS:false
                },
                exclude: /(src\/main\/webapp\/index.html)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    digest: 'hex',
                    hash: 'sha512',
                    name: 'content/[hash].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /manifest.webapp$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'manifest.webapp'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            // Ignore warnings about System.import in Angular
            { test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/, parser: { system: true } },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
                BUILD_TIMESTAMP: `'${new Date().getTime()}'`,
                VERSION: `'${utils.parseVersion()}'`,
                DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
                // The root URL for API calls, ending with a '/' - for example: `"https://www.jhipster.tech:8081/myservice/"`.
                // If this URL is left empty (""), then it will be relative to the current context.
                // If you use an API server, in `prod` mode, you will need to enable CORS
                // (see the `jhipster.cors` common JHipster property in the `application-*.yml` configurations)
                SERVER_API_URL: `''`
            }
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/css', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/css' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/lib', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/lib' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/content/', to: 'content' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/content/primeng/', to: 'content/primeng/' },
            // jhipster-needle-add-assets-to-webpack - JHipster will add/remove third-party resources in this array
            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' }
        ]),
        new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
            output: {
                groupBy: [
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/nl/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/nl.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/fr/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/fr.json" }
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfills', 'main', 'global'],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/' })
    ]
});
```

I'm not very familiar with Webpack so thanks for any hints.